# vb.net Displaying an animated Gif while waiting a process

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, datatable, animated-gif

I am running a code to export a datatable to Excel. Since this is taking a while I dont want to confuse the user and display an image [image: Loader]

```
Dim _excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        PictureLoading.Visible = True

        wBook = _excel.Workbooks.Add()
        wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = GetTableForCompleteArchive()
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
        PictureLoading.Refresh()
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex += 1
            _excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next
        PictureLoading.Refresh()
        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            rowIndex += 1
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex += 1
                _excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
            Next
        Next
        PictureLoading.Refresh()
        wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        Dim strFileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Export.xlsx"  '"C:\datatable.xlsx"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
        End If
        PictureLoading.Refresh()
        wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
        wBook.Close()
        _excel.Quit()

        PictureLoading.Visible = False
```

The problem is the image freezes and is not animating. Is there a way to get the image animating while waiting for the process?

Comment: One solution would be to move your excel processing to a background thread allowing you display the animation on the UI thread.

Comment: @Hursey could you show me how to do that?

Comment: Have a read up on https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?680130-Correct-way-to-use-the-BackgroundWorker

Comment: @Hursey I got it working with the Backgroundworker

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TotalArchiveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EXCELToolStripMenuItem.Click

        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        'call this method to start your asynchronous Task.
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        'display the loading image
        PictureLoading.Visible = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        'call the function to export to Excel
        Export2Excel()
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        '' This event is fired when your BackgroundWorker exits.
        '' It may have exitted Normally after completing its task, 
        '' or because of Cancellation, or due to any Error.
        PictureLoading.Visible = False

    End Sub
```

My function is run from inside the `Backgroundworker_DoWork`. The image is set to visible when I click `TotalArchiveToolStripMenuItem` and set to not visible when the `BackgroundWorker` is completed.